# Encourage user to not give URL-only answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Many questions on Gaming SE can be answered by just posting a link.

As I just answered [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7404/gifts-and-party-members) question, someone else posted the same link but with no further explanation. 
Everybody knows that in a year or so this link might lead to a 404.

So it would be nice to encourage the user to summarize the concepts on the linked page. 
Probably a hint when adding links on answers or something similar.

What do you think about it?

edit:
 In order to guard against misunderstandings: Copy&Paste of the linked (copyrighted) material is not a solution. But rephrasing of concepts/solutions would be nice.

Comment: As long as we avoid copy-pasting copyrighted material, I'm 100% for this!

Comment: related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/963/plethora-of-non-answer-answers

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Yes, that's true. I actually forgot to add this to my question, thx.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127/should-we-link-to-content-or-contain-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voting.

If a user simply posts a link to a resource, feel free to paraphrase the contents. You may do so in a brand new answer or (if you're feeling particularly generous) by [editing the summary right in](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/5049/revisions).

When users see that [original content pays](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/5015/timeline), they'll hopefully work harder for their answers in the future :)

Comment: Personally, I feel it's polite to at least comment on the answer and tell the user that more than a link would be helpful, *before* creating the similar-but-more-detailed answer.  Assuming they aren't serial link posters.